# Скролл до элемента в окне браузера с помощью pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Имею задачу автоматизировать работу в браузере с помощью `pywinauto`. Все было хорошо, пока не добрался до нижней невидимой части страницы с целью пощелкать по ссылочкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод print_control_identifiers() всех их отображает, часть вывода представлена ниже.

```
import time
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop

stackoverflow = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe https://stackoverflow.com"
Application(backend='uia').start(stackoverflow)
time.sleep(5)
mozilla = Desktop(backend='uia').window(class_name='MozillaWindowClass')
print(mozilla.print_control_identifiers())
```

Часть вывода:

```
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ListItem - 'Questions'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Questions', 'ListItem', 'QuestionsListItem', 'Questions0', 'Questions1', 'ListItem0', 'ListItem1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Questions", control_type="ListItem")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Hyperlink - 'Questions'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Hyperlink56', 'Questions2', 'QuestionsHyperlink']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Questions", control_type="Hyperlink")
```

Но при попытке кликнуть падает исключение:

```
mozilla.child_window(title="Questions", control_type="Hyperlink").click_input()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\root\work\grabbers\so_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    mozilla.child_window(title="Questions", control_type="Hyperlink").click_input()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 222, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Questions', 'control_type': 'Hyperlink', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers — Mozilla Firefox', MozillaWindowClass, 26805080>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

Однако, если ручками проскроллить до нужного элемента, все нажимается прекрасно.
Вопрос: возможно ли с помощью `pywinauto` реализовать прокрутку окна к нужному элементу?

Comment: Вообще, странно, что Web UI решили с помощью десктопной тулы автоматизировать. Selenium в этом плане надёжнее и умеет в headless mode. А тут постоянно активный десктоп нужен. Для хрома специальный ключ запуска нужен для включения accessibility на страницах. В общем, не самый лёгкий путь выбрали, хотя как-то работать тоже будет. И даже на Линуксе и Макоси тоже в будущем будет.

Comment: Есть на то необходимость. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть более гибкий перечень элементов, чем то, что выводит print_control_identifiers().

Comment: Насчёт гибкости проясните, плиз. Больше возможных ключевых слов в child_window для каждого элемента? Это можно сделать в будущих релизах. Или что-то другое?

Comment: Отдайте их списком. И если свойств добавите, хуже точно не будет.

Comment: Свойств добавим (уже в ветке). Списком отдадим через `.find_all()` для спецификации окна.

Answer (score 0):

Так-то `mozilla.wheel_mouse_input(wheel_mouse_input=-10)` - это на 10 рубчиков вниз крутнуть, например.